# Android studio show only basic files

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to code my android apps in Xamarin studio where you have nothing more than resources files, class files and activity classes. (In the solution explorer)

Now I switched to Android studio and I can barely find the stuff I am looking for. I mean there are so many different things on my project explorer it's a real mess.

I'm sure all these options are very useful but I prefer a clean interface and to look for these options when I need them.

Is there a way in Android studio to see only the mandatory files like I would in Xamarin ?

My current view :

> [image]

Comment: Those files are common ground when you do native Android.

Comment: @Emmanuel So there is no way to filter it even more ?

Comment: I do not think so. I think it will beneficial if you understand what each of those files do.

Comment: @Emmanuel I will give it a shot and try to deal with it.. thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can choose different filtering for the **Packages** view by using the popup in the view's title bar:

[image: Package view of IDE, showing popup menu]

which will hide some of the project-level build files and such. However, you're still going to see a number of resource folders; as others have commented, this comes with the territory when doing native Android development. You can start reading about how the resource system works by looking [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html).

Comment: Just don't forget that some of those files are there, especially `build.gradle` -- you may need to edit it by hand at some point.

Comment: Of course. I understand all those files are important. I just don't want to go through a maze everytime I'm developing. I love simple, straightforward, minimal UI and don't mind searching for an hidden feature that I will use once or twice. I will read the link you sent though, it might change my mind. Thanks again.